# Is it possible to create unique enum fields in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, unique

Suppose I have a `Role` class like this:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base

  enum code:{manager: 1, employee: 2}

end
```

So every role has a class that identifies it as a manager / employee / etc.

Now I can find a list of my role(s) with the `employee` code by doing:

```
Role.employee
```

Now I intend for each role to be uniquely identified by its code, but to get the sole `employee` role, I still need to search for `Role.employee.first`, which feels unintuitive.

Is there any way to set up the `code` atribute as 'unique', so that `Role.employee` can give me the `employee` role directly?

Comment: Some information on enums that might help: https://hackhands.com/ruby-on-enums-queries-and-rails-4-1/

Comment: by unique do you mean 'the only one'? so that there is only one Role record with the `role.code == :employee`?

Comment: @lakesare Yes, I've tried to rephrase my question a little to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks @Dawcars, it's a good source of info but I don't think it addresses the idea of uniqueness.

Comment: Ah. In this case, I'd just redefine `def self.manager` permodel, or even get rid of enum and manually add `validates_inclusion_of :code, :in => ['manager', 'employee'] `,  `validates_uniqueness_of :code`, and define `self.manager` methods etc as per the need.